# How do I do a recursive, in-file replace?

Tags: linux, unix, file, replace, cpu-word

Let's say I want to scan through every file in this directory (recursive, too).

And I want to replace `happy.magic` with `sad.apps.magic`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i 's,happy.magic,sad.apps.magic,g' {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Eric is right, but just to be clear:

```
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i "s/happy\.magic/sad\.apps\.magic/g" {} \;
```